# Laravel 5.3 - Pull data of polymorphic table in one query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Using the polymorphic relationship `likeable`, I have setup `authors` and `books` as `likeable_type` in `likeable_items` table.

Here are the models:

```
class Like extends Model {
    public function likeable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Author extends Model {
    public function likes(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable');
    }
}

class Book extends Model {
    public function likes(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable');
    }
}
```

I want to use **one efficient query to** pull them both in with their respective data, paginated by 10, something like this does not work (I commented the code to show what is needed in each step).

```
$likeableData = 
DB::table('likeable_items')
  // We want to fetch additional data depending on likeable_type
  ->select(['books.title', 'books.author_name', 'book_counts.like_count']) // when likeable_type = 'book'
  ->select(['authors.name', 'authors.country', 'authors.age', 'author_counts.like_count']) // when likeable_type = 'author'
  ->leftJoin('books', 'books.id', '=', 'likeable_items.likeable_id') // when likeable_type = 'book'
  ->leftJoin('book_counts', 'book_counts.book_id', '=', 'likeable_items.likeable_id') // when likeable_type = 'book'
  ->leftJoin('author_counts', 'author_counts.author_id', '=', 'likeable_items.likeable_id') // when likeable_type = 'author'

  // We want to have distinct results, based on unique id of book/author
  ->distinct()

  // We want to order by the highest like_count, regardlress of likeable_type
  ->orderBy('book_counts.like_count', 'desc') // order by highest like_count when likeable_type = 'book'
  ->orderBy('author_counts.like_count', 'desc') // order by highest like_count when likeable_type = 'author_counts'

  // We want to paginate the mixed results
  ->paginate(10);

return $likeableData;
```

How can I get the mixed results back of the highest liked `author`/`book` by `likes_count`, with their respective data, paginated by 10?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the table schema:

```
Table: likeable_items
       - id
       - likeable_id (book_id or author_id)
       - likeable_type (book or author)

Table: books
       - id
       - title
       - author_name

Table: book_counts
       - book_id
       - like_count

Table: authors
       - id
       - name
       - country
       - age

Table: author_counts
       - author_id
       - like_count
```

Comment: Did you look on the sql outcome of your current approach? this doesnt look very efficient to me

Comment: This is why I am posting, because I am not sure how to do what I have in the comments as an efficient query :)

Comment: Does your `Like` model use the `likeable_items` table? Can you post the schema of the 3 tables you are querying?

Comment: @EricTucker I updated the question with the schema :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it from your `Like` model without the need for the counts tables with some sub selects and grouping like:

```
$likes = Like::select('*')
    ->selectSub('COUNT(*)', 'total_likes')
    ->with('likeable')
    ->whereIn('likeable_type', [Book::class, Author::class])
    ->groupBy('likeable_type', 'likeable_id')
    ->orderBy('total_likes', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Then to access the values:

```
foreach($likes as $likedItem) {
    $likedItem->total_likes;
    if($likedItem->likeable_type === Book::class) {
        // Your book logic here
        $likedItem->likeable->title;
        $likedItem->likeable->author_name;
    } else {
        // Your author logic here
        $likedItem->likeable->name;
        $likedItem->likeable->country;
        $likedItem->likeable->age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change the schema and have more than one query a possible solution would be:

**Update Schema:**

```
Table: likeable_items
   - id
   - likeable_id (book_id or author_id)
   - likeable_type (book or author)
   - like_count

Table: books
    - id
    - title
    - author_name

Table: authors
    - id
    - name
    - country
    - age
```

**Update Model:**

```
class Like extends Model 
{

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isBook()
    {
        return ($this->likeable_type === Book::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAuthor()
    {
        return ($this->likeable_type === Author::class);
    }
}
```

Except you need `book_counts` and `author_counts` for a special piece of logic on your system, I would just remove them and move `like_count` to `likeable_items`.

`like_count` is a property common to `books` and `authors` so I think that it's reasonable to place it on `likeable_items`.

**Querires:**

```
$likes = Like::orderBy('like_count', 'desc')
             ->paginate(10);

$likeable_id = $likes->pluck('likeable_id');

$books = Book::whereIn('id', $likeable_id)->get()->groupBy('id');
$authors = Author::whereIn('id', $likeable_id)->get()->groupBy('id');
```

So, at this point get the best 10 is trivial. 
To fetch the data instead we use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) and then [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby) with `whereIn`.

About this point, please consider that if you are using `likeable_items` to dispatch the `id` for `books` and `authors` the two `whereIn` will return just the data you need.
Instead, if you use `likeable_items` just to cache `books` and `authors` ids, you will potentially have some data you don't need.

**How to display the content:**

```
@forelse ($likes as $item)

    @if ($item->isBook())
        $books[$item->likeable_id][0]->title;
        $books[$item->likeable_id][0]->author_name;
    @else
        $authors[$item->likeable_id][0]->name;
        $authors[$item->likeable_id][0]->country;
        $authors[$item->likeable_id][0]->age;
    @endif

@empty

@endforelse
```

**Final Considerations:**
Using this approach you will:
- change your schema and update your model 
- you won't use `morphTo`, 
- you do 3 queries instead of 1 but are not complex
- you can directly use `paginate`
- you always use `id` for the secondary queries (which is good for performance)

The only "dark side" as I said is that you may have some content you don't need in `$books` and `$authors` in case you are not dispatching the ids from `likeable_items` but I think is a reasonable trade-off.